# I'm using the Node.js ORM Sequelize and its command line client and I'm having difficulty successfully executing migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my app I'm using the Sequelize-CLI to set up tables and run migrations to a PostgreSQL database. Here's my code:

.sequelizerc

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'database.json'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('db', 'migrate')
}
```

config/database.json

```
{
"development": {
    "username": "Sol",
    "password": null,
    "database": "experiments",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
    },
"production": {
    "username": "Sol",
    "password": null,
    "database": "experiments",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
    } 
}
```

I created two models in my models directory and created a migration file using `sequelize migration:create` in my db/migrate directory. Finally I run `sequelize db:migrate` to run the migration, however when I check the PostgreSQL database there are no new tables created. I get this response after running the command:

```
Loaded configuration file "config/database.json".
Using environment "development".
    at new module.exports.Sequelize (/Users/Sol/src/projects/tests/Node.js/toVisit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:182:13)
    at getSequelizeInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/tasks/db.js:203:10)
    at getMigrator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/tasks/db.js:208:21)
    at Object.module.exports.db:migrate.task (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/tasks/db.js:23:7)
    at Gulp.gulp.task.aliases (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/helpers/gulp-helper.js:14:14)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out the problem was Sequelize-CLI was unable to locate PostgreSQL on account it didn't have the necessary modules `pg` and `pg-hstore` installed. I discovered this while programmatically using Sequelize through my server. It threw me an error a portion of which can be seen here:

```
throw new Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported.
        ^
Error: The dialect postgres is not supported. (Error: Cannot find module 'pg-hstore')
```

From there a simple google search led me to a little more detailed explanation and now I am able to run my migrations successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Install the *pg-hstore*:

```
npm install pg-hstore --save
```

And set the dialect in your *config/database.json*:

```
 dialect: 'postgres'
```